# Importance of Execution Environment in Eclipse Project Settings

Tags: java, eclipse

I was going through how the execution environment works in eclipse project settings. What I read is that `-source` parameter conveys what version your source code is compatible with. What does it mean? Does this mean if I have JDK 1.8 in my build path and I've used Java 8 features (Lambda Expression or Stream API) in my codebase and I set `-source` version to 1.7, it will give me error during compilation?

Why would someone want to use lower values of `-source` and `-target` parameters if they are actually building their application using comparatively higher java version?

PS: I already went through many Stackoverflow articles related to this but still struggling to understand the actual use.

Comment: You might want to give the compiled code to someone running an older version of Java than you are

Comment: Yes, you're basically right. If you set the source to 1.7 the compiler won't allow any language features introduced with higher versions. This could be used if you want to use a newer JDK but still build your code to be compatible with lower versions (although you'd also need to make sure you don't use any features of newer libraries, e.g. `String.join(...)` would be compatible with 1.7 but was added in 1.8 only) or to disallow newer features for some reason (some companies seem to be wary of those features and want to check them out first before allowing their devs to use them).

Comment: @Thomas I didn't get.. String.join(...) was added in 1.8 but still be compatible with 1.7. Isn't this contradicting with your own statement of not using features of newer libraries?

Comment: @greg-449 What sense does it make to use higher version of something without actually using it's capabilities?

Comment: You might be using the newer features in other projects, but need to target an older Java in one project. Note that in Eclipse the compiler is part of Eclipse (called "ecj"), not the installed Java.

Comment: What I mean is: let's say your using a JDK with version 1.8+ but set the source level to 1.7.  Now the compiler would complain if you'd use lambdas etc. but it wouldn't complain if you used `String.join(...)`. However, you should not use this method if your goal is to support runtimes that only have version 1.7 since that method wouldn't be available there - so be careful not to use it.

Comment: @Thomas The 'Use -release option' setting in the Eclipse preferences can deal with that - Eclipse will check the APIs used match the compliance level.

Comment: @greg-449 good to know, will check that out :)